Can an ADO pipeline that specifies multiple repositories be used as a resource for another pipeline and reference commit ids?
I have two pipelines, PipelineA and PipelineB
Pipeline A is run against repository 1, and references repositories 2 and 3.
Pipeline B is also run against Repository 1, and references repositories 2 and 3. It references pipeline A.
I need to checkout the same commits for repositories 2 and 3 in both pipelines; instead of specifying them manually for pipelineB I'd like to automatically pick them up from the referenced pipelineA if possible.
I know that in the repository ref arg I can use variables like
resources:
  pipelines:
    -pipeline: PipelineA
     source: PipelineA  

  repositories:
    -repository: Repo2
     type: git
     name: Repo2
     ref: $(myVar)

    -repository: Repo3
     type: git
     name: Repo3
     ref: $(myVar)

and if I were referencing a single repo pipeline I could do something like
$(resources.pipeline.PipelineA.sourceBranch)

My question is, is there any way I could combine those two for each specific repo? Like the below
resources:
  pipelines:
    -pipeline: PipelineA
     source: PipelineA  

  repositories:
    -repository: Repo2
     type: git
     name: Repo2
     ref: $(resources.pipeline.PipelineA.repositories['repo2'].sourceBranch)

    -repository: Repo3
     type: git
     name: Repo3
     ref: $(resources.pipeline.PipelineA.repositories['repo3'].sourceBranch)


Just a note: Yes, I understand having pipeline with the two nearly identical inputs is backwards and probably wrong and should be one pipeline instead; totally not the scope of this question; if I could put it all into one pipeline I would be external factors that I can't really get into prohibit that.


is there any way I could combine those two for each specific repo

Azure DevOps doesn't support such syntax $(resources.pipeline.PipelineA.repositories['repo2'].sourceBranch).
According to Pipeline resource variables,

In each run, the metadata for a pipeline resource is available to all jobs as predefined variables. These variables are available to your pipeline only at runtime.

But the resources are resolved before runtime, therefore, you can't use pipeline variables in the repo resource.
Besides, if you set the ref of the repo resource to one branch, you can only ensure two pipelines checkout the same branches instead of the same commits.
To ensure two pipelines checkout the same commits, we need consider some workarounds. In order to give you more accurate advice, please answer the questions in the comments to help us understand your scenario.


What is the pipeline resource used for? Trigger pipelineB or download artifact from pipelineA? 2. What are the repo resources used for? Trigger the pipeline, extend template or something else? Does using git command to checkout in a command line task meet your needs?


There are some different workarounds can let two pipelines checkout the same commits. For example, 1. Tag the commits of repo2/3 using the runid of the pipelineA. Trigger pipelineB using REST API in pipelineA and pass the runid as variable/parameter to pipelineB's checkout taks. 2. Tag the commits of repo2/3 using the runid of the pipelineA. PipelineA triggers pipelineB uing pipeline resource and checkout repo2/3 in cmd task.  The workarounds depend on your actual situation.
